# Permission denied when run a scala script to get data from hive?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, environment-variables

i wanna to simulate different user to get their hive table data, however it seems that the env is always keep the original value. what should i do to correct it.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#

import scala.sys.process._
val Array(db, table, user) = args
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", user)
val command = Seq("hive", "-e",
f"""SELECT * FROM `${db}`.`${table}` limit 5000""")
println(command)
command.!
```

and the error is as follows

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/bugfix/hive_cdh5.14.4/runtime/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.14.4.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: SemanticException Unable to determine if hdfs://**************** is encrypted: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=11, access=READ, inode="****************":hive:hive:drwxrwx--x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkAccessAcl(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:3870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPathAccess(FSDirectory.java:3841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getEZForPath(FSNamesystem.java:9403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getEZForPath(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getEZForPath(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getEZForPath(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)
```

i.ll appreciate if u could do me a favor

Comment: it works after i change to this wat
`
#!/bin/sh
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=$3
exec scala -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#

import scala.sys.process._
val Array(db, table, user) = args
val command = Seq("hive", "-e",
f"""SELECT * FROM `${db}`.`${table}` limit 5000""")
println(command)
command.!
`

Comment: You should try using jdbc rather than invoking the deprecated Hive cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.setProperty` does not set environment variables. As you commented, you'll need to export the variable via the shell environment before starting the Scala process. Otherwise find a way to cause `System.getenv()` map to return the value you're trying to set